# Using zelig for simulation

Tags: r, package, regression, simulation

I am very confused about the package Zelig and in particular the function sim. 
What i want to do is estimate a logistic regression using a subset of my data and then estimate the fitted values of the remaining data to see how well the estimation performs. Some sample code follows:

> data(turnout)
>
> turnout <- data.table(turnout)
>
> ## Shuffle the data
>
> turnout <- turnout[sample(.N,2000)]
>
> ## Create a sample for regression
>
> turnout_sample <- turnout[1:1800,]
>
> ## Create a sample for out of data testing
>
> turnout_sample2 <- turnout[1801:2000,]
>
> ## Run the regression
>
> z.out1 <- zelig(vote ~ age + race, model = "logit", data = turnout_sample)
>
> summary(z.out1)
>   Model:

Call:
z5$zelig(formula = vote ~ age + race, data = turnout_sample)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
-1.9394  -1.2933   0.7049   0.7777   1.0718

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) 0.028874   0.186446   0.155   0.876927
age         0.011830   0.003251   3.639   0.000274
racewhite   0.633472   0.142994   4.430 0.00000942

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

```
Null deviance: 2037.5  on 1799  degrees of freedom
```

Residual deviance: 2002.9  on 1797  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2008.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

Next step: Use 'setx' method

> ## Set the x values to the remaining 200 observations
>
> x.out1 <- setx(z.out1,fn=NULL,data=turnout_sample2)
>
> ## Simulate
>
> s.out1 <- sim(z.out1,x=x.out1)
>
> ## Get the fitted values
>
> fitted <- s.out1$getqi("ev")

What i don't understand is that the list fitted now contains 1000 values and all the values are between 0,728 and 0,799.
1. Why are there 1000 values when what I am trying to estimate is the fitted value of 200 observations?
2. And why are the observations so closely grouped?

I hope someone can help me with this.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The first question:
 From the signature of `sim` (`sim(obj, x = NULL, x1 = NULL, y = NULL, num = 1000`..) you see the default number of simulations is 1000. If you want to have 200, set `num=200`.
However, the `sim` in this [example from documentation](http://r.iq.harvard.edu/docs/zelig/3.5.3/Examples.html) you use, actually generates (simulates) the probability that a person will vote given certain values (either computed by `setx` or computed and fixed on some value like this `setx(z.out, race = "white")`).
So in your case, you have 1000 simulated probability values between 0,728 and 0,799, which is what you are supposed to get.